# Search for audio files on phone using React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native to develop a music app and I'm stuck trying to figure out the best way to search for and play audio files already saved on the clients phone. I'm just not sure what would be the best modules/libraries to solve this problem, or whether the iOS/Android OS allows this type of access to user files at all.

I'm using [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound) to play audio files and I've found the [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) module and this looks close to what I feel I need to search for audio files. There's a readDir function, but you pass it directory path constants like MainBundlePath, CachesDirectoryPath, DocumentDirectoryPath etc:

```
// require the module
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

// get a list of files and directories in the main bundle
RNFS.readDir(RNFS.MainBundlePath)
```

With:
 1. MainBundlePath - The absolute path to the main bundle directory
 2. CachesDirectoryPath - The absolute path to the caches directory
 3. DocumentDirectoryPath - The absolute path to the document directory

Would any of these directories be where I look to find audio files already stored on the clients phone?

Comment: Related to [How to search through iPhone filesystem downloads folder for mp3 files in react native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259710/how-to-search-through-iphone-filesystem-downloads-folder-for-mp3-files-in-react).

Answer (score 6):

**This is a 3 step process** that requires storage permissions (since you're getting data from the local storage)

1. Install [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions) to get storage permission from the user, then go to your **AndroidManifest.xml** located at **YourProject/android/app/src/main/** and add the following:

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   ```
2. Create functions to request and check for storage permissions before requesting for the songs, for example:

```js
    componentDidMount() {
      Permissions.request('storage').then(response => {
        this.setState({ photoPermission: response })
      })
     }
```

3. Then create another function to get the data from the device (You can also pass some parameters or filters in your function--follow the `react-native-get-music-files` docs)

```js
  _getSongs =() =>{
       Alert.alert('seen')
       MusicFiles.getAll({

            }).then(tracks => {
              console.log(tracks)
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
       })
     }
```

So, Here's what the final code looks like

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Alert} from 'react-native';
import MusicFiles from 'react-native-get-music-files';
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
       storagePermission:''
     }

    componentDidMount() {
      Permissions.request('storage').then(response => {
            this.setState({ storagePermission: response })
      })
     }


    _getSongs =() =>{
       Alert.alert('seen')
       MusicFiles.getAll({

            }).then(tracks => {
              console.log(tracks)
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
       })
     }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                <Text onPress={this._getSongs}>get songs</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Then you get a JSON array of the list of the users songs which looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    id : 1,
    title : "La danza del fuego",
    author : "Mago de Oz",
    album : "Finisterra",
    genre : "Folk",
    duration : 132132312321, // miliseconds
    cover : "file:///sdcard/0/123.png",
    blur : "file:///sdcard/0/123.png",
    path : "/sdcard/0/la-danza-del-fuego.mp3"
  }
]
```

Good luck!

Comment: P.s: this method is for Android, the iOS version will be posted soon. Respect to @Dante-Cervantes who's the creator of react-native-get-music-files.

Comment: Can we have the IOS part?

Comment: thanks for try to tag me, im under re-develop this plugin, currently now works for Android, but getting there to be compatible with iOS

Answer (score 1):

[react-native-get-music-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-music-files) is an npm package that searches for all music files on the local storage and sd card.

```
import MusicFiles from 'react-native-get-music-files';

MusicFiles.get(
  (success) => {
     //this.saveSongData(success)
  },
  (error) => {
       console.log(error)
  }
);
```

The function returns an array of objects that you can loop through like so:

```
[
  {
    id : 1,
    title : "La danza del fuego",
    author : "Mago de Oz",
    album : "Finisterra",
    genre : "Folk",
    duration : 132132312321, // miliseconds
    cover : "file:///sdcard/0/123.png",
    blur : "file:///sdcard/0/123.png",
    path : "/sdcard/0/la-danza-del-fuego.mp3"
  }
]
```

Unfortunately, it currently supports Android only.

Comment: hi, im the owner of that package, and now it supports ios too

Comment: Im using it and gives me an error, its been two years

Comment: @DanteCervantes thanks so much for this great package. I am currently struggling to use this package now for the past couple of days but I do not get any response or files. I keep getting a catch error. Please can you guide me through it. ??

Comment: Any solution for ios??

Comment: It finally works now for iOS and Android!