# How to search through iPhone filesystem downloads folder for mp3 files in react native

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm working on an react native ios app where I want to look through the iPhone's downloads folder for .mp3 files that I can play. I've found a library [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) but right now I am only able to see files added to my app and I can't figure out how to search for `.mp3` files already on the iPhone. Any advice on libraries to use or code would be appreciated.

Code for my project: https://github.com/Laybium/laybium

Comment: You can use the MPMedIaLibrary from the media player framework https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer

Comment: Have you found a way?

Comment: Are you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS apps have access only to their sandboxes. There's no such a thing as a Downloads folder, because there's no folder all apps may share.

Comment: Is there anyway I can access the sandbox of itunes and play the music files in itunes and play them?

Comment: That's impossible. iTunes is not different from the rest of the apps. All of them have access only to their sandboxes. Well, if you create an App Group, you may share data within it, but there's no way to add iTunes into. It's for apps created by the same developer.

Comment: could you send a link to the app?

Comment: All file explorers I've found have integrations from the known services/apps (dropbox, google drive, widows office, etc.) to get files from them. They don't talk to file system directly. The exception is images, but you don't need them anyway.

Comment: okay. The app isn't all the app store yet but all the code is here: https://github.com/Laybium/laybium